# tabularx with multicolumn and multirow

Tags: tabularx

I need a table with this format:

[image]

I need to use tabularx. I already tried something but it doesn't work... I keep getting the error message '! Missing number, treated as zero.'

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} | X | p{0.5cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | p{0.5cm}  > {\centering\arraybackslash}X | p{0.5cm} }
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Code}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{2}{}{\textbf{Richtige Bewertung}}} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Falsche Bewertung}} \\ \cline{4-7}
& & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{False Negatives}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{False Positives}} \\ \hline\hline
$\boldsymbol{A_1}$ & \StrokeFive\StrokeFive\StrokeTwo (12) & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{A_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{B_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{B_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{C_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{C_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{D_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\boldsymbol{D_2}$ & & & & & & \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Can anyone help me with this?
Thank you very much in advance.
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten a lot of vertical bars `|` in the declaration of your table.

Also, you must remember, that if you use `\multicolumn`, you are redefining the look of the column, including the vertical bars.  You have to repeat the definition of vertical bars in that case.

Next, you were missing some important packages, for example `multirow`, to get the `\multirow`-command working.  Package `ifsym` with option `[misc]` to make the command `\StrokeFive` working.

You should think about using the `>{$}...<{$}` magic, to save from repeatedly inserting the `$` in the first column.

I was not able to find a package for the command `\boldsymbol`.  I replaced it by `\mathbf` which *might* be the same.

First example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}        % for \StrokeFive

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |% <-- was missing!
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1cm} | 
  X | 
  p{0.5cm} | 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | 
  p{0.5cm}  | % <-- bar missing
  > {\centering\arraybackslash}X | 
  p{0.5cm} | % <--- bar missing
}
  \hline
  \textbf{Code}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Richtige Bewertung}}
%  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \multirow{2}{}{\textbf{Richtige Bewertung}}}
  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Falsche Bewertung}} \\ 
  \cline{4-7}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{False Negatives}} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{False Positives}} \\ 
  \hline  %% in your example was only one line!
$\mathbf{A_1}$ & \StrokeFive\StrokeFive\StrokeTwo (12) & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{A_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{B_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{B_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{C_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{C_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{D_1}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
$\mathbf{D_2}$ & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Second example, using `>{$}...<{$}` to save typing:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}        % for \StrokeFive

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ |% <-- was missing!
  >{\centering\arraybackslash $}p{1cm} <{$} | % <---- added math mode
                                % magic here! 
  X | 
  p{0.5cm} | 
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}X | 
  p{0.5cm}  | % <-- bar missing
  > {\centering\arraybackslash}X | 
  p{0.5cm} | % <--- bar missing
}
  \hline
  \multicolumn{1}{|c}{\textbf{Code}} % \multicolumn gets rid of math
                                % mode here!
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Richtige Bewertung}}
%  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{ \multirow{2}{}{\textbf{Richtige Bewertung}}}
  & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\textbf{Falsche Bewertung}} \\ 
  \cline{4-7}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{False Negatives}} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{False Positives}} \\ 
  \hline %% in your example was only one line!
\mathbf{A_1} & \StrokeFive\StrokeFive\StrokeTwo (12) & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{A_2} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{B_1} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{B_2} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{C_1} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{C_2} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{D_1} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\mathbf{D_2} & & & & & & \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Result for both examples:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much :) That was really helpfull, especially the >{$}...<{$} part is really nice. I did not know that.

Comment: My pleasure if it helped.